# Sorting an array in C using pointers

Tags: c, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of float values using pointers. I can't seem to understand why my for loop doesn't sort the values. I've tried debugging and it seems that this program works up until the the third for loop where I am actually doing the sorting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main() {
    float f_array[20] = { 0.25, 0.93, 0.66, 0.74, 0.34, 0.36, 0.63, 0.00, 0.01, 0.50, 0.33, 0.47, 0.31, 0.51, 0.64, 0.55, 0.61, 0.62, 0.57, 0.66 };
    float* ptr_1 = f_array;
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("Unsorted values: %f\n", *ptr_1);
        printf("\n");
        ptr_1++;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 20; k++) 
        {
            if (*(ptr_1 + k) > (*(ptr_1 + (k + 1)))) {

                k = *(ptr_1 + k);

                *(ptr_1 + k) = *(ptr_1 + (k + 1));

                *(ptr_1 + (k + 1)) = k;
            }
        }
    
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("Sorted Values: %f\n", *ptr_1);
        printf("\n");
        ptr_1++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using pointers for this? Instead of `*(ptr_1 + k)` just use `f_array[k]`

Comment: In the loop before, you were incrementing the pointer, so when you go to the sorting loop, the pointer isn't pointing to the start of the array (like it probably should), but to the last element of the array.

Comment: @V0_1D, minor correction: It is pointing one past the last element. That is still not the start of the array, as it should.

Comment: `*(ptr_1 + k)` is out-of-range even if `k = 0` after doing `ptr_1++;` 20 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to start by telling you that you have a too little understanding of the pointer vs array thing. But I know you would not listen, so I'll fix your code first:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    float f_array[20] = { 0.25, 0.93, 0.66, 0.74, 0.34, 0.36, 0.63, 0.00, 0.01, 0.50, 0.33, 0.47, 0.31, 0.51, 0.64, 0.55, 0.61, 0.62, 0.57, 0.66 };
    float* ptr_1 = f_array;
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("Unsorted values: %f\n", *ptr_1);
        ptr_1++;
    }

    ptr_1 = f_array;
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 19; k++) {
            if (*(ptr_1 + k) > (*(ptr_1 + (k + 1)))) {
                float tmp = *(ptr_1 + k);
                *(ptr_1 + k) = *(ptr_1 + (k + 1));
                *(ptr_1 + (k + 1)) = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    ptr_1 = f_array;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("Sorted Values: %f\n", *ptr_1);
        ptr_1++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

In short there were three big mistakes:

1. incrementing `ptr_1` and not resetting it to f_array
2. using `k+1` with `k=20`
3. using `k` as a temporary variable to swap two floats... this triggers a warning in Visual Studio: `warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data`.

This code still generates `warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'double' to 'float'`, because you are using doubles to initialize your array. Why do you use floats at all? In the 64 bits era the default for floating point should be double, unless you really need to save memory.

Don't disable a warning by default without thinking: why `#pragma warning(disable : 4996)`? What does it mean? Is it needed?

Finally, remember that when you write `f_array[k]` you are using the **pointer** operator `[]`. `f_array` is treated as a **pointer** to the first element of your array. It means `*(f_array + k)`. Using pointers doesn't mean that you need to point to the first element and increment the pointer. That's why I introduce arrays after pointers.

You could have written `ptr_1[k]` and `ptr_1[k+1]` and still used pointers.
And, in my opinion, you would be using pointers also when writing `f_array[k]`. But some other instructors would disagree.

One final comment: I hate that sorting (is it bubble sort without an early stopping possibility?) and I didn't check if it's correct. If you want simple O(n²) sorting, just go for [Selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort): less swapping.